# How to separate a list into two list at '\n'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to separate a list in different lists at '\n'. For example, if I have a list like this one:

```
l = ['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'john', '\n', '\n', 'nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you']
```

I'd like to separate the items this way:

```
l = [['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'john'], ['nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you']]
```

Can someone help me?

Some code that I tried to write:

```py
l = ['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'john', '\n', '\n', 'nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you']
lst = []
ls = []
for word in l:
    if word != '\n':
        ls.append(l)
    else:
        lst.append(ls)
print(lst)
```

Comment: Where is your code as [mre] and what isthe problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just wanted to append `word` to the list `ls`. Also, clear the partial list at the newlines like so:

```
lst = []
ls = []
for word in l:
    if word != '\n':
        ls.append(word)
    else:
        if len(ls) > 0:
            lst.append(ls)
            ls = []
if len(ls) > 0:
            lst.append(ls)
print(lst)
```

resulting in

```
[['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'john'], ['nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [itertools.**groupby**:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = ['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'john', '\n', '\n', 'nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you']
>>> l = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(l, lambda s: s != '\n') if key]
>>> l
[['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'john'], ['nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you']]
```